# How to make rest service download smoothly given byte array and content type available at server side?

Tags: java, arrays, rest, download, jersey-2.0

I am getting an array of bytes   `byte[] contentBytes = content.getContentStream();` and type of content `content.getType()` from the third-party service. I need to make this downloadable from rest service. Currently, I am doing it in the following way:

```
public Response retrieveContent(@PathParam("id") long contentId, @QueryParam("action") String action) {
        ContentStreamBean content = repository.getContentStream(contentId);
        final byte[] contentBytes  = content.getContentStream();
        StreamingOutput fileStream =  new StreamingOutput() {
          @Override
          public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            output.write(contentBytes);
            output.flush();
          }
        };
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(fileStream);
        response.type(content.getType());
        if ("download".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
            response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + content.getName()); // TO force download
        } else {
            response.header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + content.getName()); // To preview
        }
        return response.build();
    }
```

How can I improve this to make download smooth at present download is happening at a time after some waiting of the request? Why is it not starting the download immediately instead of waiting to get the complete file once though I am using `StreamingOutput` from rest service?

Comment: What is the meaning of "taking too much time"? Can you share the metrics according to download requirements(like connection speed , filesize etc.)?

Comment: If you are using Streams to use Buffered Streams. But you have to pay attention, for example you have a problem when you use multiple BufferedStreams for example with the java Socket API

Comment: @Niton I didn't get what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: You should profile what the time-consuming part in your method is. Is it the acquisation of the byte array from the thrid-party library? If so, you might not be able to improve overall performance unless the service offers some other ways or you are in control of the `getContentStream` method. The method name at least is misleading in that you get a byte array instead of a stream. If you are in control you might also post the code for retrieving the byte array (or stream?) from the 3rd party servcie.